# How to extrude to meet an angled face?

Tags: modeling, extrude

Imagine extruding a wall profile from the flat floor plane, constraining the extrusion to the Z-Axis. It must meet the pitched ceiling angle above. Is there a simple way to perform this without knife cuts after the fact? I'm currently using the TinyCAD add-on to extend edges to the ceiling face, but this is tedious and I have to perform this function very frequently. Any simpler ideas that I've missed?[image: MyDescriptiveImage]

Thanks for the clear reply, Robin. Your second solution worked perfectly. Those snap options do so much more than I realize. The first, however, is still giving me trouble. The vertexes do not snap to the roof angle, and they are variably snapping to whatever point on the roof edge that I am hovering over. I try it a second time with "Align Rotation to Snap Target" at the end of the gif, the result is just crazed. I must have some setting incorrect. See here:

[image: AnotherChallenge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the snap options 'Face', and 'Project individual elements':

[image]

2. Select the top face(s) of wall, and have a view open looking down the desired axis of projection. (The right-side one, here)

[image]

3. With the mouse in the projection view, Hit <kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Robin! I've edited the original question with a gif to show an issue I'm having with your first proposed solution. The second solution is perfect, however.

Comment: @CentralProcess .. got you. I keep getting caught out by that.. thinking of other applications. I'll edit the answer. Really, we need to be able to set a custom snap orientation in the same way as we can set a custom transform orientation.. I don't think there's a reason, in principle, it can't be implemented. Thanks.

Comment: Very cool. What’s proper protocol here? Should I delete my edit about your now-gone alternative solution?

Comment: I think we leave the comments in ... I just didn't want any future readers to be misled by my plain wrong first suggestion. Your illustration is useful.