# How can I project a face to meet another object's surface?

Tags: faces, extrude, project

is there a quick way to move a face to meet another, but keeping the connected edges at their current angle? I'd like to make my yellow side wall meet the red post, filling the gap between the two. Simply moving the face along the Y axis would change the angle of the wall's slope - I want to keep it as it is. I've tried this method: [How to extrude to meet an angled face?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108807/how-to-extrude-to-meet-an-angled-face) but it doesn't seem to work (the selected face ends up at a strange angle). [image: Yellow wall and red post]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide with, (after establishing its direction with a small move,) <kbd>C</kbd>  the clamp released, so it can continue beyond existing edges. The Snap is set to 'To:Face' and 'With: Active', and left switched on, so you don't have to do too many things at once...

[image]

Comment: Wow ... I have more to learn than I thought ... I used it just for edge extension didn't know it works for trapezoid (✷‿✷)

Comment: Ah! @vklidu! Can you remember which answer of yours it was that did that sand-dune feedback thingy without a camera? I wanted to point [this Q](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/253628/35559) at it...

Comment: I can get this to work with new geometry, but for some reason it's refusing on my current mesh - the yellow projection lines go a bit crazy. Any guesses what might be the issue?

Comment: @derekjackson check for a pathological mesh? (Duplicate vertices, inverted normals, etc.) Any other modifiers on the mesh? Any bevels screwing it up?

Comment: @RobinBetts Hi, thanks, but all seems okay... No modifiers or bevels, all normals pointing outwards, no strange geometry. The wall was generated as a simple cube which I then applied a Boolean to, to cut to meet another element. This has been applied though - so it's now basically a simple 6-sided mesh, as far as I can see?

Comment: @derekjackson OK, if you can strip down  a minimal example of what's not working and post to  https://pasteall.org/blend/ , we could have a look and try to work out what's going on in this case?

Comment: Thanks @RobinBetts. Here's the link : https://pasteall.org/blend/71f218ef7af14e668d9fcbc3ecaa5f56

Comment: Hi @derekjackson. In that file, the rail had duplicate vertices. (Pick one up, and move it, you'll see the hidden ones behind). A 'M' (Merge) > 'By Distance' with all verts selected, fixed it for me. I hope that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for investigating @RobinBetts. Is there a method for automatically finding or displaying duplicate vertices? Or is it a case of just going round and moving them to check?

Comment: I think you soon get out of the habit of making them.. (e.g. avoiding the main cause: the gotchas in the extrude and inset operations.. which, unless _fully_ cancelled with ctrl-Z,  leave 0-length extrusions behind them) . And you get used to the signs they are there.. like the behaviour of your file :). M > By Distance tells you how many verts were merged, in the info bar.